# How can i send a merge request?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge

i have changes done in master locally and i don't want to just push them, instead i want to create a new branch and have it have everythink in it then merge it with master.

git status showed that all the changed files has been added using git add and commited using git commit -m "something" but not pushed, not sure if this will impact the later steps.

What have i done:

```
# Start a branch called new-feature
git checkout -b new-feature master
# Edit some files
git add <file>
git commit -m "something"
# Merge in the new-feature branch
git checkout master
git merge new-feature
git branch -d new-feature
```

but that didn't work

Comment: Why don't you just create a branch (`git checkout -b <name>`), then push this branch and open a Pull Request?

Comment: You mean push the new branch right not master? if so that's exactly what i want can you fix my commands to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a branch that contains the current state of your current branch (in this case, master branch). To do that, do run this line:

```
git checkout -b <new_branch_name>
```

Running this line, you will be in your newly created branch, containing the local commits you made. Now, you can push the changes from this new branch (`git push -u origin <new_branch_name>`) and, after that, open a Pull Request to the master (or to any branch you desire).

To open a Pull Request, you can access the repository page (for instance, `https://github.com/<your_user>/<your_repo>`) and press the button `new pull request`. Then you just select the source and destiny, add a message and create it.

Comment: Added as requested. I hope it helped you

Comment: That explanation is valid for Github, but just to make it clear, Github's pull requests are Merge requests on Gitlab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/